# Delete or remove expandable listview item onclick of button in the child items

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Please look into my requirement and suggest a solution. Okay here is my requirement, I have an expandable-list-view with one group item and one child item which contain a button. On the click of the child button, I want to remove the complete group. How can I do this?

here is my activity is as follows

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ExpandableListViewAdapter expandableListViewAdapter;
    List<String> Tasklist;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> childitemslist;
    Window window;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
            window=this.getWindow();
            window.setStatusBarColor(getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor));

        }

        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Pending Tasks");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        
        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expandable_listview);
        showList();
        expandableListViewAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(TaskActivity.this, Tasklist, childitemslist);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListViewAdapter);

            }


    private void showList() {
        Tasklist = new ArrayList<String>();
        childitemslist = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        Tasklist.add("new task-1");
        Tasklist.add("new task-2");
        Tasklist.add("new task-3");
        Tasklist.add("new task-4");
        Tasklist.add("new task-5");
        Tasklist.add("new task-6");
        Tasklist.add("new task-7");

        List<String> description1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        description1.add("Description-1 should be done in this task before 29th should be done in this task before 29th should be done in this task before 29th");
        List<String> description2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        description2.add("Description-2");
        List<String> description3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        description3.add("Description-3");
        List<String> description4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        description4.add("Description-4");
        List<String> description5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        description5.add("Description-5");
        List<String> description6 = new ArrayList<String>();
        description6.add("Description-6");
        List<String> description7 = new ArrayList<String>();
        description7.add("Description-7");

        childitemslist.put(Tasklist.get(0), description1);
        childitemslist.put(Tasklist.get(1), description2);
        childitemslist.put(Tasklist.get(2), description3);
        childitemslist.put(Tasklist.get(3), description4);
        childitemslist.put(Tasklist.get(4), description5);
        childitemslist.put(Tasklist.get(5), description6);
        childitemslist.put(Tasklist.get(6), description7);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please put code

Comment: @ShaluTD please have a look into code

Comment: Pls add the adapter code